# How to give RANDOM background color to list of buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Aim: I am trying to make a candy crush game with buttons as candies. So it is needed that the buttons have random colors (among 4 - red/ green/ blue / yellow).

What I tried:  I created 4 classes of colors in css -

```
      .pink{
               background-color: red;
      }
      .blue{
               background-color: blue;
      }
      .green{
               background-color: green;
      }
      .brown{
               background-color: yellow;
      }
```

And tried to assign these classes to the buttons randomly. But I am new to jQuery. I searched on the web and I tried the following script:

```
        var colors = Array ('red','blue','green','yellow');

        var candy  = document.querySelectorAll("button");

        for(var i=0;i<colors.length;i++){

            candy[i].style.background-color=colors[i];
        }
```

It is not working. What can I try to resolve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a random value from a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-a-random-value-from-a-javascript-array)

Comment: yes @theusaf it helped. thanx a lot guys.

Answer (score 0):

To get random number use `Math.random()`,
but why it is not setting background color using `for loop` because you need to use `camelCase` while setting CSS attribute using javascript.

```
for(var i=0;i<colors.length;i++){

    candy[i].style.backgroundColor=colors[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a random item from the list using this code:

```js
const randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
```

You can use your css by setting `candy[i].className = randomColor`;

You can also directly set the styles using `candy[i].style.backgroundColor = randomColor`

Example snippet:

```js
const colors = ["pink","green","blue","brown"];
const candy  = document.querySelectorAll("button");
for(var i=0;i<candy.length;i++){
  const randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  candy[i].className = randomColor;
}
```

```css
.pink{
  background-color: red;
}
.blue{
  background-color: blue;
}
.green{
  background-color: green;
}
.brown{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<button>hello</button>
<button>hello</button>
<button>hello</button>
<button>hello</button>
<button>hello</button>
```

Comment: it worked. thank u for the swift response from the bottom of my heart. Now the problem is how to detect 3 or more candies (buttons)  of same color/class in adjacent. How should I do it ? Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

hope all is well! this works for me:

```
function random_bg_color() {
var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
var z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
var bgColor = "rgb(" + x + "," + y + "," + z + ")";
```

console.log(bgColor);

```
document.body.style.background = bgColor;
}
```

random_bg_color();

This will work if you are using Javascript. good luck!